# I need to display all employees which were hired before their managers. Can somebody help me?

Tags: sql

[image: Table photo]

I need to run an SQL query which will display all the employees who were hired before their managers and they have the minimum salary for his function.

```
SELECT ENAME,JOB, SALAR FROM EMP
WHERE JOB = 'SALESMAN'
OR JOB = 'CLERK'
OR JOB = 'ANALYST'
```

Comment: Can you clarify about "and they have the minimum salary for his function"? Can you share the result you expect to get for this data?

Comment: @Mureinik probably a translation mistake for "job_id"

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select . . .
from (select e.*, m.hiredate as mgr_hiredate,
             min(salar) over (partition by job) as min_salar
      from emp e left join
           emp em
           on e.mgr = m.empno
     ) em
where hiredate < mgr_hiredate and salar = min_salar;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can join `EMP` to itself to add details about each employee's manager (we're interested in his `HIREDATE`). Later in `WHERE` section you can check that manager's `HIREDATE` is later than corresponding employee's.

You can also pre-calculate all minimal salaries for each job, then join this information to each employee and later you can check that employee's salary is equal to the minimal.

```
SELECT EMPNO, ENAME
FROM EMP e
INNER JOIN EMP m ON e.MGR = m.EMPNO
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT JOB, MIN(SALAR) as MINSALAR
  FROM EMP
  GROUP BY JOB
) s ON s.JOB = e.JOB
WHERE m.HIREDATE > e.HIREDATE AND e.SALAR = s.MINSALAR
```